# Pentaho CDE nested sql query

Tags: pentaho

We have set a nested SQL query on pentaho CDE .
Query :

```
select dataissue.value,count(value) as nbreticket,substring(issue.entry,1,3) 
from DataIssue,issue where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' 
and dataissue.issue = issue.id and issue in ( select issue
from dataissue,issue where dataissue.issue = issue.id and value = 'récit' 
and substring(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) and issue in ( select issue 
from dataissue,issue where dataissue.issue = issue.id and value = 'Fermée' 
and substring(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) and issue in ( select issue 
from dataissue,issue where dataissue.issue = issue.id 
and field = 'point_d_effort' and substring(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) 
group by dataissue.value
```

And we have set a bar chart component  with that query .

But there is no result in the bar chart .

Does Pentaho cde support nested sql Query

Comment: can you provide sample result of that sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pentaho cde supported nested sql Query.

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3),dataissue.value,COUNT(VALUE) AS nbreticket
FROM DataIssue,issue WHERE FIELD = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' 
AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND issue IN ( SELECT issue
FROM dataissue,issue WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE = 'récit' 
AND SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) AND issue IN ( SELECT issue 
FROM dataissue,issue WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE = 'Fermée' 
AND SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) AND issue IN ( SELECT issue 
FROM dataissue,issue WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id 
AND FIELD = 'point_d_effort' AND SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) 
GROUP BY dataissue.value
```

you can put these sql and run and see.

If there is no result in bar chart.

=> You can do one thing, Go to your  dashboard location  meaning where ever you save that dashboard that location.

=> In these location CDA file is there. Select that CDA file and click "**open in new window**". After one new window will appear and select that query and see that result is display or not.

=> If result is displayed there is no problem in that sql.

Thank you..

Comment: thank you , you are right the query is returning and empty table  in cda . But it is runing in Mysql . So the query actually works in Mysql

Comment: you can seperate main sql in to three sql's. By using priority in component in cde meaning which sql is running first or second like that. eg:- If you give priority one that sql will execute first. Based on priority sql's will execute.If you follow these step your problem will be solved i think. If you satisfy my answer can you a tick mark for these answer. Thank you ..

Comment: can you give more details  on how to implemen this . And wich component to use .